# How to straighten hair on a spheres edge

Tags: particles, hair

I want to make it so that all hair particles are sticking normal to the sphere. My problem is that some of these are floating around. My guess is thats the case because I beveled the edge of the sphere. Is there a way to select individual hairs and delete them?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot select single hairs, but you can use vertex groups for that.

Choose for density your vertex group:

[image]

VG:

[image]

result:

[image]

Or you could even use the Length vertex group, with which you can do something like this:

[image]